# Stanford Parser for Python: Output Format

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am currently using the Python interface for the Stanford Parser.

```
    from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser
    import os

    os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] ='/Users/au571533/Downloads/stanford-parser-full-2016-10-31'
    os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/Users/au571533/Downloads/stanford-parser-full-2016-10-31'
    parser=StanfordParser(model_path="edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")

    new=list(parser.raw_parse("The young man who boarded his usual train that Sunday afternoon was twenty-four years old and fat. "))
    print new
```

The output I get looks something like this:

```
    [Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['The']), Tree('JJ', ['young']), Tree('NN', ['man'])]), Tree('SBAR', [Tree('WHNP', [Tree('WP', ['who'])]), Tree('S', [Tree('VP', [Tree('VBD', ['boarded']), Tree('NP', [Tree('PRP$', ['his']), Tree('JJ', ['usual']), Tree('NN', ['train'])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['that']), Tree('NNP', ['Sunday'])])])])])]), Tree('NP', [Tree('NN', ['afternoon'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBD', ['was']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('JJ', ['twenty-four']), Tree('NNS', ['years'])]), Tree('ADJP', [Tree('JJ', ['old']), Tree('CC', ['and']), Tree('JJ', ['fat'])])])]), Tree('.', ['.'])])])]
```

However, I only need the part of speech labels, therefore I'd like to have an output in a format that looks like word/tag.

In java it is possible to specify -outputFormat 'wordsAndTags' and it gives exactly what I want. Any hint on how to implement this in Python?

Help would be GREATLY appreciated. 
Thanks!

PS: Tried to use the Stanford POSTagger but it is by far less accurate on some of the words I'm interested in.

Comment: Could you edit in an example of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: For the sentence in the code above, something like: ['The/DT', 'young/JJ', 'man/NN'], either a list of string-like items, or a list of tuples or a table would be fine. The bottom line is: I do not need the Dependency Tree information, but only parts of speech for each word. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the NLTK classes for the Stanford parser](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/stanford.html), you can see that the the `raw_parse_sents()` method doesn't send the `-outputFormat wordsAndTags` option that you want, and instead sends `-outputFormat Penn`.
If you derive your own class from `StanfordParser`, you could override this method and specify the `wordsAndTags` format.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser

class MyParser(StanfordParser):

        def raw_parse_sents(self, sentences, verbose=False):
        """
        Use StanfordParser to parse multiple sentences. Takes multiple sentences as a
        list of strings.
        Each sentence will be automatically tokenized and tagged by the Stanford Parser.
        The output format is `wordsAndTags`.

        :param sentences: Input sentences to parse
        :type sentences: list(str)
        :rtype: iter(iter(Tree))
        """
        cmd = [
            self._MAIN_CLASS,
            '-model', self.model_path,
            '-sentences', 'newline',
            '-outputFormat', 'wordsAndTags',
        ]
        return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
```

Comment: Sounds good! Would it be possible for you to show a quick example of how to do it? I'm not that much of a good programmer yet :D Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Still a small issue: it throws an error saying "MyParser has no attribute '_make_tree'", which seems to be required by _parse_trees_output in stanford.py > GenericStanfordParser(ParserI). Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, I see. Try inheriting from `StanfordParser` instead.